# How to detect the active connection

Tags: mysql, visual-foxpro

I'm developing a desktop application using MySQL as database motor. Also I'm using an unique connection by quickness issues. My question is, how can i detect if the connection is active before sending the query?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a good chance that the answer will depend on what language you're using.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Visual Fox Pro 9.0 as Dev. Tool.

Comment: Launch the query and see if it succeeds? ;-P I know nothing about FoxPro but many APIs have a `ping` feature. Look for that in the manual.

Comment: That's the way i'm doing it. i thought there was another specific function but i'm afraid i'll keep with this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a connection opened with the SQLCONNECT() function, you can try a simple statement using something like:

```
SQLEXEC(handle, "SELECT 1", "testcursor")
```

If a "Connection handle is not valid" error occurs, the connection isn't valid.